# Does anyone use $\subset$ for proper subset anymore?

Tags: notation

I belong the the group of people who still write (not necessarily proper) subset as $\subseteq$ to avoid any confusion with *proper subset*, which I notate $\subsetneq$; I usually do not use $\subset$ at all. But now that I think about it, I have not seen anyone use $\subset$ for *proper subset* in any post-1960s textbooks. Is it still used for that at all, or can that use of the $\subset$ symbol be considered archaic?

Comment: When I was a student at the university of Copenhagen 11 years ago, only very few people there didn't use $\subset$ for *proper subset*. But I suppose it depends a lot on what you do.

Comment: I currently study in Aarhus; it is strange how the conventions apparently vary from university to university. At Aarhus, it appears that all topologists use $\subset$ for subset, while all analysts use $\subseteq$. It varies among the algebraists.

Comment: I have seen people use both $\subset$ and $⊆$ for subset but never seen anyone use $\subset$ for proper subset only. At the very least not in any papers or books that were written fairly recently or any conferences/lectures I have been to.

Comment: I think the use of $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ was originally intended to reflect the use of $<$ and $\le$. However, since the early days of set theory, it has become increasingly obvious that subset is the more important notion, and that it is used *much* more than proper subset. So I do indeed see the idea of letting the most simple symbol stand for "subset" (even if I do not use it for that myself).

Comment: I only use $\subset$. I don't like the way $\subseteq$ looks. If I needed to stress that $A$ was a proper subset of $B$ then I would write $A\subset B$, $A\neq B$. Just personal preference.

Comment: @Gaussler: That difference between toplogist and analysts is what I hinted at with my last sentence.

Comment: Update: It turns out that $\subset$ is gaining popularity among analysts as well at my university.

Comment: In notes intended for students, I only use $\subseteq$, and I mention properness in words rather than symbols when it is needed. I suspect I do the same thing in my professional publications, out of habit, but I haven't checked all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is hard to say what is common or archaic use of a symbol, because it would require studying a large number of publications.

The use of $\subset$ for *proper subset* and $\subseteq$ for *subset* is obviously motivated by analogy with $<$ and $\le$. On the other hand, using $\subsetneq$ for *proper subset* and $\subset$ for *subset* is motivated by the fact that *proper subset* is a concept which is seldom needed in actual mathematical context. (I cannot easily create a meaningful example where *proper subset* is required.)

At my university (Budapest), only $\subset$ was ever used and always meant *subset*. No one ever used $\subseteq$ (nor $\subsetneq$), because the concept *proper subset* was seldom used, and the simpler form, $\subset$ had a better use for the more common meaning *subset* (a kind of economical choice of symbol). In fact, these symbols had a certain "childish" or at least "high schoolish" look. On the rare occasion that *proper subset* was needed, one would write $X \subset Y, X \ne Y$, in order to emphasize this constraint.

Below I collected some of the global resources that may be useful in deciding one way or other:

## ISO

ISO has a standard for math symbols, but it is targeted towards natural sciences and technology rather than mathematics itself.

The standard is behind a paywall, so only the Wikipedia page can be linked here: [ISO 80000-2:2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2). An eralier, obsolete standard (which nevertheless is very similar) is available on Wikipeda: [ISO 31-11:1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11).

- Item 2.5.7 defines $B \subseteq A$ as "$B$ *is included in $A$, $B$ is a subset of* $A$".
- Item 2.5.8 defines $B \subset A$ as "$B$ *is properly included in $A$, $B$ is a proper subset of* $A$".

However; even the ISO document contains a remark for 2.5.7 and 2.5.8 that defines an alternative: $\subset$ is *subset* and then $\subsetneq$ must be used for *proper subset*.

## Wikipedia

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) on math symbols takes the same approach, preferring the pair $\subseteq$ / $\subset$, but mentioning $\subset$ / $\subsetneq$ as well.

## Unicode character names

Unicode defines these operators in the [Mathematical Operators](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf) block and uses the following names:

- U+2282 $\subset$ SUBSET OF
- U+2286 $\subseteq$ SUBSET OF OR EQUAL TO
- U+228A $\subsetneq$ SUBSET OF WITH NOT EQUAL TO

This seems to prefer the $\subset$ / $\subsetneq$ pair, but is not decisive (ambiguity is very common with Unicode names, unfortunately).

## HTML entities

In the official [HTML entity list](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) (renamed to "named character reference" since HTML 5):

- $\subset$ is `&subset;`
- $\subseteq$ is `&sube;`
- $\subsetneq$ is `&subne;`

Again, this seems to favor the $\subset$ / $\subsetneq$ pair.

## Summary

Where I come from, professional mathematicians prefer $\subset$ for *subset*. *Proper subset* is virtually not used. If a single character were still required for that case, it would be $\subsetneq$. But better avoid that as well.

In education and applied sciences one can see $\subseteq$ for *subset* more often.

There are also some mentions of $\subset$ meaning *proper subset*, but I have never seen an actual example where it was used like that. In order to avoid confusion, one could (in fact, should) use $\subsetneq$ for *proper subset* even if $\subseteq$ is used for *subset*.

Bottom line: use of $\subset$ meaning *proper subset* is ill-advised in any case because it creates confusion. Use either

- $\subset$ for *subset* and (if absolutely necessary) $\subsetneq$ for *proper subset* (my preference), or
- $\subseteq$ for *subset* and $\subsetneq$ for *proper subset* (totally unambiguous choice).

Comment: I can think of a few times when proper subsets come into play. Perhaps the most important is that a maximal ideal is defined to be a proper subset of a ring.

Comment: "Professional mathematicians use $\subset$ only" is totally wrong; both conventions are common among professional mathematicians.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thank you for the comment. I updated the answer to reflect it and reworded to a less biased form. I have seen some more papers recently that use $\subseteq$ for *subset* . Yet as to the original question, which was about $\subset$ meaning *proper subset* I still believe that is a confusing use of the symbol.

Comment: @CarlMummert: thank you for the comment. I changed the wording somewhat.