conventional notations for subsets/super-sets and proper subsets/proper super-sets
Background
$A\neq B\quad \tag{1}$
Notations:
$\subset,\subseteq, \subseteqq,\nsubseteq,\nsubseteqq,\subsetneq,\subsetneqq,\varsubsetneq,\varsubsetneqq \tag{2}$
$\supset,\supseteq, \supseteqq,\nsupseteq,\nsupseteqq,\supsetneq,\supsetneqq,\varsupsetneq,\varsupsetneqq \tag{3}$
Questions
I want to ask given sets $A, B, A\neq B$ as in $(1)$, what are the conventional notations that are used to denote $A$ is a strict proper subsets of $B$ ($A, B$ can be groups, rings, vector spaces, modules, functions, etc), amongst the options from $(2)$.
Also, for the case that $A$ is a subset of $B$ where $A$ might or might not be a strict proper subset of $B$.  What are the conventional choice notations that are usually chosen from the list in $(2)$.
Similar questions apply to the case of $B$ being a superset of $A$, in cases, where it is a strict inclusion, and not necessarily strict inclusion.
What are the usual notational conventions can be chose from $(3)$
Thank you in advance.

There are no universally accepted conventions for this. My personal convention is to use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$.

@GerryMyerson when I look through the list of symbols from latex symbols list.  I thought there are matheamtical reasons why there are four different ones:  $\subsetneq,\subsetneqq,\varsubsetneq,\varsubsetneqq$ for when a subset is a strict proper subset.

Not really. Just sometimes people have preferred / been exposed to different stylizations in the past, there is no fundamental reason. About the biggest distinction amongst them is that $\subset$ sometimes means "proper subset" (so $\subsetneq$) and sometimes just "subset or possibly equal to" (so $\subseteq$). Hence why I'm with Gerry on their choice of notation, since it's the least ambiguous choice with the most typographical pleasantness

For what it's worth, too, I sometimes use $\le$ for substructures (subgroups, subrings, subspaces, subfields...) as opposed to $\subseteq$ - as an indication you're focusing in part on the algebraic structure - and have seen others do so as well, so this might be worth considering.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895305/why-should-subset-denote-subset and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114920/does-anyone-use-subset-for-proper-subset-anymore and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950945/subset-notation and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456885/negation-of-proper-subset and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476590/confusion-in-symbol-of-subset and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565339/notational-definition-a-subset-b and probably a dozen others.

Just note that when the stroke is through the whole symbol as in $\nsubseteq$, then the relation as a whole is negated: "is not a (proper or non-proper or any, whatever the nonstroke symbol means) subset of". Now that I wrote this, I miss $\not\mkern.5mu\subsetneq$ from the list

@HagenvonEitzen actually, don't $\nsubseteq$ also mean not a strict proper subset, or does it mean a proper strick subset?

$A\nsubseteq B$ means that $A\subseteq B$ is false. The horrible notation $A\not\mkern.5mu\subsetneq B$ means that $A\subsetneq B$ is false. So because $B\subseteq B$ is true and $B\subsetneq B$ is false, we see that $B\nsubseteq B$ is false and $B\not\mkern.5mu\subsetneq B$ is true. For what it's worth, simply memorize that $\subseteq$ means "is subset or equal" and $\subsetneq$ means "is subset and not equal"; thereby, it does not matter when reader and writer have different opinions on whether "subset" implicitly means "proper subset" or not.

If the world were sensible, we would use $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ to completely mirror the standard use of the relations $\leq$ and $<$ on the real numbers. Anything else is an abomination. Unfortunately, some use $\subset$ when they should say $\subseteq$, so $\subset$ is ambiguous. So because a few people ruin it for everyone else, we must use abominations like $\subsetneq$ if we want to be clear.

@Arthur I still am not clear on Hagen's comment about the notation:  $\nsubseteqq$  My understanding  is if $A\subset B$, and it is a strict proper subset.  That would mean there exists a $b\in B$ and $b\not\in A$.  So how is that different from $\nsubseteqq$?

@Seth Because ${1}\not\subseteqq {2}$, since ${1}\subseteqq {2}$ is false. On the other hand, we do not have ${1}\subsetneqq {2}$. That is the difference.

@Arthur wait, i forgot to ask, do $\nsubseteqq$ and $,\subsetneqq$ mean the same?

@Seth No, they don't mean the same. As evidenced by the fact that ${1}\not\subseteqq {2}$ is true (the statement says that "${1}\subseteqq {2}$ is false", which we can all agree on), but ${1}\subsetneqq {2}$ is false (that statement claims that "${1}\subseteqq {2}$ and also ${1}\neq {2}$", which is bogus).

Note that the slash covers the part that is claimed to be untrue. So when the slash goes through the whole symbol, you have to look at what the entire symbol says, then negate that as a whole. If the slash goes through part of the symbol, then only that part is claimed to be untrue.

@Arthur so $A\nsubseteq B$ simply mean that neither $A$ nor $B$ is a subset of each other, and $A \subsetneqq B$ means $A$ is a not a proper subset of $B$?  An example would be: ${1}\nsubseteq{2}$ since ${1}\neq {2}$, and ${1} \subsetneqq {2}$ is false since ${1}$ is not a subset of or is not a strict proper subset of ${2}$

@Seth No. $A\not\subseteq B$ means exactly that $A$ is not a subset of $B$, because it's the negation of $A\subseteq B$. It says not a single thing about the truth of $B\subset A$, there is no "each other" in that statement. So we do, in fact, have ${1, 2}\not\subseteq {2}$, as well as ${1}\not\subseteq {2}$.

@Arthur and $A\subsetneqq B$ would mean $A$ is a strict proper subset of $B$?

@Seth Yes, it would. It is $A\subseteqq B$, with the added slash to signify $A\neq B$.

@Arthur thank you for being so patient with answering my questions.  :)
